# Que versión anouar/paypalpayment instalar si uso laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

Hola pregunto esto porque actualmente tengo el siguiente error:

^ ErrorException {#244 ▼
  #message: "sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\web100\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalModel.php"
  #line: 179
  #severity: E_WARNING
  trace: {▶}
}

He buscado porqué el error y veo en un post que es por la paypal\rest-api-sdk-php, yo he cargado la libreria  usando **"anouar/paypalpayment":"~1.0"** ¿cual sería la correcta, no sé si tenga que ver la versión de laravel con la que estoy trabajando pero por si acaso uso 5.6?.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

si a alguien le sirve la solución que encontré fue bajar la versión de php reinstalando Xamp en su versión 7.1.11